# Continue outer-loop several times, when exit inner-loop (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, break, continue

I've one inner loop and one outer (records in database). The outer loop (json) make a filter based of a couple of fields (eg : begin/end => 0 : 0.5 >>> IDs 114 to 159).

The Table :

```
ID    begin     end  status  FK1_field  FK2_field FK3_field FK4_field  FK5_field    report_id

114    0        0.5    1      NULL      13          8         142       44            1
115    0        0.5    1      NULL      13          8         61        45            1
158    0        0.5    1      NULL      13          8         142       45            1
159    0        0.5    1      NULL      13          8         61        44            1
116    0.5      1.5    1      NULL      13          8         142       45            1
117    0.5      1.5    1      NULL      13          8         131       45            1
118    1.5      2.5    1      NULL      13          8         142       45            1
```

*The result is looping over the inner loop* (eg : 4 records/lines (*) ).

But, when I exit the inner loop, I must loop over the outer loop 4 times (*) to get the ID 116 (and filter begin/end) => 0.5 : 1.5.

Indeed, I can loop over only the inner loop and test with an 'if' the same couple times. But I think the filtering is more elegant. 
For now, I think looping when exit the inner loop is stupid.

The code :

```
highways = tools_cronjob.getAPI(API_URL + action, headers)
for highway in highways:
    print('>>>>> Highway : %s ' % highway['name'])

    # all the prpk, same values like the table
    prpk_by_highway = tools_cronjob.getAPI(API_URL + actions_api['prpk_by_highway'] + "%s" % (highway['id']), headers)

    # get all prpk by highway
    for prpk in prpk_by_highway:
        filtered_by_begin_end = [pr_pk for pr_pk in prpk_by_highway if pr_pk['begin'] == prpk['begin']]

        # each couple of prpk 'begin' and 'end'
        for filter_prpk in filtered_prpk_by_begin_end:
            # some stuff
            print (filter_prpk)
            # when I exit, for eg, I must continue looping (prpk in prpk_by_highway) starting the couple begin/end : 0.5 : 1.5
```

So the first loop is 4 records, the second is 2 and the third just 1.
The Json :

```
[
   {
      'end':0.5,
      'begin':0.0,
      'status':'1',
      'department':{
         'number':'13',
         'id':13,
         'name':'Bouches-du-Rhône'
      },
      'meteozone':{
         'id':44,
         'name':'137'
      },
      'commune':None,
      'massif':{
         'meteozones':[
            {
               'id':44,
               'name':'137'
            },
            {
               'id':45,
               'name':'138'
            },
            {
               'id':104,
               'name':'831'
            },
            {
               'id':105,
               'name':'832'
            }
         ],
         'id':142,
         'name':'Sainte-baume'
      }
   },
   {
      'end':0.5,
      'begin':0.0,
      'status':'1',
      'department':{
         'number':'13',
         'id':13,
         'name':'Bouches-du-Rhône'
      },
      'meteozone':{
         'id':45,
         'name':'138'
      },
      'commune':None,
      'massif':{
         'meteozones':[
            {
               'id':45,
               'name':'138'
            }
         ],
         'id':61,
         'name':'Garlaban'
      }
   },
   {
      'end':0.5,
      'begin':0.0,
      'status':'1',
      'department':{
         'number':'13',
         'id':13,
         'name':'Bouches-du-Rhône'
      },
      'meteozone':{
         'id':45,
         'name':'138'
      },
      'commune':None,
      'massif':{
         'meteozones':[
            {
               'id':44,
               'name':'137'
            },
            {
               'id':45,
               'name':'138'
            },
            {
               'id':104,
               'name':'831'
            },
            {
               'id':105,
               'name':'832'
            }
         ],
         'id':142,
         'name':'Sainte-baume'
      }
   },
   {
      'end':0.5,
      'begin':0.0,
      'status':'1',
      'department':{
         'number':'13',
         'id':13,
         'name':'Bouches-du-Rhône'
      },
      'meteozone':{
         'id':44,
         'name':'137'
      },
      'commune':None,
      'massif':{
         'meteozones':[
            {
               'id':45,
               'name':'138'
            }
         ],
         'id':61,
         'name':'Garlaban'
      }
   },
   {
      'end':1.5,
      'begin':0.5,
      'status':'1',
      'department':{
         'number':'13',
         'id':13,
         'name':'Bouches-du-Rhône'
      },
      'meteozone':{
         'id':45,
         'name':'138'
      },
      'commune':None,
      'massif':{
         'meteozones':[
            {
               'id':44,
               'name':'137'
            },
            {
               'id':45,
               'name':'138'
            },
            {
               'id':104,
               'name':'831'
            },
            {
               'id':105,
               'name':'832'
            }
         ],
         'id':142,
         'name':'Sainte-baume'
      }
   },
   {
      'end':1.5,
      'begin':0.5,
      'status':'1',
      'department':{
         'number':'13',
         'id':13,
         'name':'Bouches-du-Rhône'
      },
      'meteozone':{
         'id':45,
         'name':'138'
      },
      'commune':None,
      'massif':{
         'meteozones':[
            {
               'id':43,
               'name':'136'
            },
            {
               'id':45,
               'name':'138'
            }
         ],
         'id':131,
         'name':'Régagnas'
      }
   },
   {
      'end':2.5,
      'begin':1.5,
      'status':'1',
      'department':{
         'number':'13',
         'id':13,
         'name':'Bouches-du-Rhône'
      },
      'meteozone':{
         'id':45,
         'name':'138'
      },
      'commune':None,
      'massif':{
         'meteozones':[
            {
               'id':44,
               'name':'137'
            },
            {
               'id':45,
               'name':'138'
            },
            {
               'id':104,
               'name':'831'
            },
            {
               'id':105,
               'name':'832'
            }
         ],
         'id':142,
         'name':'Sainte-baume'
      }
   }
]
```

What is the best solution ?

Thanks
F.

Comment: Could you please post an executable minimal example, as described in [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And what is your table? Is it `prpk_by_highway`?

Comment: I post a part of code. And yes, the table is exactly the in the "The table : " section.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to group the entires by begin/end, right? And you do this by looping all entries, then looping all entries again to find the ones with the same begin/end? Have you considered using a dictionary or `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: @fabrice No, could you please follow the link I posted and post a code snippet which we can actually execute? We don't know what API_URL is. Also posting URLs is not good. Better post a snippet of `highways`. And I know that the table is in "The table:" section. I can read. But **I don't know what variable in your code is referencing to the table**. My guess was `prpk_by_highway`, but I'm not a clairvoyant.

Comment: @Scotty1- I can't post an execute code 'cause the URL is in my local VM :(. I just edit my post adding a json resulting getAPI function (prpk_by_highway)

Comment: @tobias_k : I never use itertools.groupby

Comment: @fabrice Then this seems like the perfect opportunity to _start_ using it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you question, you want to group the entires by the `begin` field. You try to do this by looping all entries, then looping all entries again (in the list comprehension) to find the ones with the same `begin`, but the outer loop continues where it left off.

Instead, I suggest using `itertools.groupby` to group the entries by that attribute. Note that this assumes that the entries are sorted by the same attribute, so if they are not, sort them first.

```
import csv, itertools, operator
with open("data.csv") as data:
    prpk_by_highway = csv.DictReader(data)
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(prpk_by_highway, key=operator.itemgetter("begin")):
        print("BEGIN", key)
        for prpk in group:
            print(prpk)
```

Here, `data.csv` is a CSV file holding your data, i.e. the same should work using your `tools_cronjob.getAPI` call. Output:

```
BEGIN 0
OrderedDict([('ID', '114'), ('begin', '0'), ('end', '0.5'), ('status', '1'), ('FK', '44'), ('report_id', '1')])
OrderedDict([('ID', '115'), ('begin', '0'), ('end', '0.5'), ('status', '1'), ('FK', '45'), ('report_id', '1')])
OrderedDict([('ID', '158'), ('begin', '0'), ('end', '0.5'), ('status', '1'), ('FK', '45'), ('report_id', '1')])
OrderedDict([('ID', '159'), ('begin', '0'), ('end', '0.5'), ('status', '1'), ('FK', '44'), ('report_id', '1')])
BEGIN 0.5
OrderedDict([('ID', '116'), ('begin', '0.5'), ('end', '1.5'), ('status', '1'), ('FK', '45'), ('report_id', '1')])
OrderedDict([('ID', '117'), ('begin', '0.5'), ('end', '1.5'), ('status', '1'), ('FK', '45'), ('report_id', '1')])
BEGIN 1.5
OrderedDict([('ID', '118'), ('begin', '1.5'), ('end', '2.5'), ('status', '1'), ('FK', '45'), ('report_id', '1')])
```

Alternatively, you could use a `dict` to put matching entries into buckets.

Comment: you understood very well :). I'm going to try using itertools.groupby. Thanks